# Not able to generate swift sdk using kotlin mulitplatform with Android studio 4.0.1

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, android-studio-4.0

I got this error after upgrading android studio to 4.0.1. It was working with android version 3.4.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
```

I am using kotlin native multiplatform. I try to generate the sdk using terminal with below command

```
./gradlew :sdk:build
```

I get below error.

Unresolved reference: KtorExperimentalAPI

It is not able to identify platform api.

```
io.ktor.client.HttpClient -> Unresolved reference:
```

Comment: You'll need to post more of your config I think. However, for native and multiplatform, Kotlin 1.3.41 is a very old version. You'll almost certainly want to upgrade to 1.4.x

Comment: to add to what Kevin said - post your dependencies block

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. As I have updated my android studio from 3.4.1 to 4.0.1. So I changed distribution url to 6.1.x and gradle version to 4.0.1.

I reverted back to distribution url to 5.4.1 (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip) and changed the kotlin version class path to 3.5.3.